# Show that $\epsilon \in (0,a)$ for some constant $a>0$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

For $a>0$ unknown fixed constant, and for $x\in (0,a) \subseteq \Re$, we have the following relationship:

$\epsilon = \frac{a}{2} + \frac12 \sqrt{\frac{(2x-a)^4 -a^4}{24(x^2-ax)}}$

I want to show that $\epsilon \in (0,a)$. Showing $\epsilon > 0$ is simple, but I'm having trouble showing $\epsilon < a$.

What I tried: assuming $\epsilon < a$ then using the relationship above and simplifying as much as possible to attempt to reach a tautology to then work backwards from that tautology as the proof. I got as far as having to show that $8x^3 - 16ax^2 + 9a^2x - a^3 < 0$ [Note: this inequality is not correct after the update], but I don't think this is a tautology (I tried to look at graphs of it for different example values of $a$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\epsilon\lt a$ is equivalent to $x^2-ax-a^2\lt 0$ since

$$\begin{align}\epsilon\lt a&\iff\frac{a}{2} + \frac12 \sqrt{\frac{(2x-a)^4 -a^4}{24(x^2-ax)}}\lt a
\\\\&\iff\sqrt{\frac{(2x-a)^4 -a^4}{24(x^2-ax)}}\lt a
\\\\&\iff \sqrt{\frac{((2x-a)^2-a^2)((2x-a)^2+a^2)}{24(x^2-ax)}}\lt a
\\\\&\iff \sqrt{\frac{(4x^2-4ax)(4x^2-4ax+2a^2)}{24(x^2-ax)}}\lt a
\\\\&\iff \sqrt{\frac{8x(x-a)(2x^2-2ax+a^2)}{24x(x-a)}}\lt a
\\\\&\iff \sqrt{\frac{2x^2-2ax+a^2}{3}}\lt a
\\\\&\iff \frac{2x^2-2ax+a^2}{3}\lt a^2
\\\\&\iff 2x^2-2ax+a^2-3a^2\lt 0
\\\\&\iff x^2-ax-a^2\lt 0\end{align}$$

Since $x^2-ax-a^2\lt 0$ holds, we see that $\epsilon\lt a$ holds.